# how to print json array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this json array and I want to output particular part in php.

{
    "status": "success",
    "country": "US",
    "countryCode": "+1",
    "regionName": "REGION NAME",
    "city": "NY"
}

example:

```
<?php
  echo "country: ".[country];
?>
```

output must be:

```
country: US
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '{ 
"status": "success", 
"country": "US", 
"countryCode": "+1",   
"regionName": "REGION NAME", 
"city": "NY" 
}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
print "country: ".$obj->{'country'}; // country: US
```

Comment: what incase if this is an api.

Comment: There should not be an issue, use the same way. If you are getting any problem, update the question.

Comment: hey can you tell me how to use second level array?
"city":{"name":"NY","fullname":"NEWYORK"}

Comment: If you have `"secondLevel": {"key":"value"}`, then `$obj->{'secondLevel'}->{'key'}` and so on

Answer (score 0):

You must convert JSON to php array:

```
$json = '{ "status": "success", "country": "US", "countryCode": "+1", "regionName": "REGION NAME", "city": "NY" }';
$a = json_decode($json,true);

echo "country: ".$a['country'];
```

Comment: @ziyamodi, it should work now, typecasted json output to array

Comment: second param in json_decode is true - it means that result will be casted into array

Comment: Try now. It was problem with JSON string. Simply remove comma after "NY"